# $f \in R([a,b]), g \in C^1([c,d])$,$g$ is strictly increasing on $[c,d]$，$g([c,d])=[a,b]$ .Is it true that $f \circ g \in R([c,d])$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

Just as the title say, is it true that $f(g(x)) \in R([c,d])$?

if the question changes to $f \in R([a,b]), g \in C([c,d])$,$g([c,d])=[a,b]$  is it true $f \circ g \in R([c,d])$ then?

Comment: Just a thought, a function is Riemann-integrable iff the set of discontinuities have Lebesgue measure zero. The composition of two almost continuous functions need not be almost continuous, hence a composition of Riemann-integrable functions need not be Riemann-integrable. One example is just taking the Thomae function and $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ extended to $0$ on $0$. I suspect continuity can control the discontinuities, but you may work out the details.

Answer (score 0):

This will be true since g is strictly increasing;you can use a partition on g that satisfies the inegrability condition to induce a partition on f via g where the mesh goes to zero.